# Hamcrest matcher for a String, where the String contains some random values

Tags: java, jmock, matcher, hamcrest

Is there a way to match the following string with any of the hamcrest matchers.

```
"{\"messageType\":\"identify\",\"_id\":\"7de9a446-2ced-4bda-af35-81e95ad2dc32\",\"address\":\"192.168.0.0\",\"port\":7070}"
```

This string is passed to a method. I use JMock expectations to match it.

The problem: "72e3a446-2fed-4bda-ac35-34e95ab3dc32" part is random generated UUID, which is generated inside the tested method. Is there a Hamcrest String matcher which will match something like

```
new StringCompositeMatcher("{\"messageType\":\"identify\",\"_id\":\"", with(any(String.class)), "\"address\":\"192.168.0.0\",\"port\":7070}" )
```

It must match that the expected string begins with `"{\"messageType\":\"identify\",\"_id\":\"` there is any string after that, and ends with the `",\"address\":\"192.168.0.0\",\"port\":7070}"`

EDIT: The solution

```
with(allOf(new StringStartsWith("{\"messageType\":\"identify\",\"_id\":\""), new StringEndsWith("\",\"address\":\"192.168.0.0\",\"port\":7070}")))
```

Comment: That would be better written `allOf(startsWith("..."), endsWith("..."))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the most elegant way to do it would be to use regexp, though there is no built-in matcher for it. However, [you can easily write your own](http://piotrga.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/hamcrest-regex-matcher/).

Alternatively, you can combine `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` with `allOf()`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like JSON. Why not use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling onto this post like me: hamcrest 2.0 has introduced a new matcher: `matchesPattern` to match a regex pattern. The following code should work:

Dependency:

```
testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.0"
```

...

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.matchesPattern;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

...

```
assertThat(
        "{\"messageType\":\"identify\",\"_id\":\"7de9a446-2ced-4bda-af35-81e95ad2dc32\",\"address\":\"192.168.0.0\",\"port\":7070}",
        matchesPattern("\\{\"messageType\":\"identify\",\"_id\":\"[0-9a-z-]+\",\"address\":\"192.168.0.0\",\"port\":7070\\}")
);
```

Note: `{` and `}` are regex characters in java so must be escaped in the matcher string.